# Publish project in visual studio using dacpac code (asp .net core)

Tags: asp.net-core

I have create project for dacpac and I want publish this code like whenever I published my api project then its automatically publish dacpac changes in database but I don't have any code for written in startup file. So please let me know if you have any idea about this. I want to load dacpac in startup file but I dont know how its code?

I have try this code in start up file

```
using (var dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(DacPacFullPath))
{
    var dacServices = new DacServices(Shared.Environment.Settings.RadanDbNameOrConnectionString());
    dacServices.Deploy(dacPackage, DatabaseName, true);
}
```

But, its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bhavesh, can you provide exception you are getting, so i can dive into it and might find solution.

[Error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqAr4.png)

Comment: Your error mentioned like you are using wrong nuget for .net core project.
Please try with below nuget link.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx